# How to find the index of an array?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, nsmutablearray, xcode4.2

I have an `NSMutableArray` instance, named `myArray`. It contains 8 button objects. How can I get the index of the button which I have taped to a integer variable?

Answer (score 3):

`NSArray` has a method called `indexOfObject`

```
- (IBAction)pushButton:(id)sender {
    NSButton *button = (NSButton *)sender;
  NSUInteger index =  [Array indexOfObject:button];

}
```

Comment: I did that like this                                         NSUInteger pos;                                                   pos = [MyArray indexOfObject:btn];                                But when i display the pos in NSLOg(NSLog(@"Pos%i",pos)) i get the output as     Pos2147483647                                             I need the out put as 0 or 1 or 2  upto 7

Comment: Hi Shaan,Could you please give more details to your query.Because the solution given by Parag Should work.

Comment: Shaan did you try logging the pos with different format specifiers? Check the "Platform Dependencies" section in the String programming guide ( http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html ). It's said that you can use %lu with NSUInteger.
NSUInteger is defined as unsigned int (or long, depending on the platform), so %i and %d shouldn't work.

Comment: @Shaan 2147483647 is the max value of a 32bit int. Is it possible that the object is not in the array, and indexOfObject is returning nil? If you ask for indexOfObject: and the object is not in the array, this is what happens. I just performed a test with an empty array, and got same results as you. Check out your code for adding the buttons to the array.